# Hiding and showing spreadsheet rows based on cell value

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I'm currently using the following code that is triggered as each cell in a column is updated.  It works fine, but takes a couple seconds for every cell, which is really cumbersome with ~200 cells to complete the sheet.  Is there any way to speed up this code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet1.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit


Dim iLastRow As Variant
Dim i As Integer
iLastRow = Range("R1:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(iLastRow, 1)
    If Range("R" & i) = "Show" Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: *triggered as each cell in a column is updated* - which column exactly? Because right now the logic is invoked whenever *any* cell changes on that sheet.

Comment: Columns C and D in Sheet1.  The above code actually works if any cell is altered, but I also tried with Target.Column narrowing it down and it didn't change the execution time at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indented the *blocks*, but not the *scopes*.

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    '<~ here
End Sub
```

Might not be the case here, but in a module with multiple procedures, it's much easier to glance at the code and see where scopes begin & end when their contents are indented.

---

> ```
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> ```

That's great: Excel isn't going to be wasting cycles repainting itself everytime you make a change. There's a problem though:

> ```
> Application.ScreenUpdating = True
> ```

If there's a runtime error anywhere between these two instructions, execution jumps out of the procedure scope and `ScreenUpdating` never gets set back to `True`, and because the error is never handled, well, you have a potentially unhandled runtime error waiting to be thrown without warning in your user's face.

Right here:

> ```
> If Range("R" & i) = "Show" Then
> ```

If `Range("R" & i)` contains an error value, VBA can't compare it to a `String` literal, and boom, runtime error 13, *type mismatch*. You should always assume that a worksheet cell can contain an error (`#VALUE!`, `#NA`, `#REF!`, etc.), and shield your code against that classic mistake using the `IsError` function:

```
If Not IsError(Range("R" & i)) Then
```

In any case, whenever you toggle `Application` state, the procedure *should* have an `On Error` statement that ensures state is cleanly toggled back in case of an error.

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '...do stuff...

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    '...handle error...
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

---

> ```
> Dim iLastRow As Variant
> ```

This means to be a row number, and given the [Systems Hungarian](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) prefix (drop it!), it has all looks of an `Integer`. It should be a `Long`, because a 16-bit signed integer couldn't work with more than 32,767 rows - and a worksheet can have many, many more rows than that. Internally, the VBA7 runtime allocates a 32-bit integer for it anyway, so you might as well use a `Long`.

Except you can't.

> ```
> iLastRow = Range("R1:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row).Value
> ```

Because it's actually an array, that contains every single value in column R!

[That's actually not a bad idea in itself](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179870/23788), except the only thing you're using it for, is to determine how many "cells" it contains - here:

> ```
> For i = 1 To UBound(iLastRow, 1)
> ```

Write code that *says what it means*, and *means what it says*. If you name a variable "last row", make it hold *the last row number* - not a variant array that contains every single value in a column. Or, name it `visibilityToggleColumn` or something similar.

`i` being an `Integer` is also problematic. Use a `Long`, so you don't need to worry about how many rows there might be - there's no reason to use an `Integer` for this.

---

This Boolean assignment is a common pattern:

> ```
> If Range("R" & i) = "Show" Then
>     Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
> Else
>     Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
> End If
> ```

So common, the latest 2.1 pre-release of [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) includes an inspection (and a quick-fix) for it:

> **Boolean literal assignment in conditional**
>
> *A member is assigned True/False in different branches of an If statement with no other statements in the conditional. Use the condition directly to assign the member instead.*

Applying the quickfix turns this:

> ```
>     If Range("R" & i) = "Show" Then
>         Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
>     Else
>         Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
>     End If
> ```

Into this:

> ```
>     Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = Not (Range("R" & i) = "Show")
> ```

Which can then be simplified to this:

> ```
>     Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = Range("R" & i) <> "Show"
> ```

---

Rubberduck also complains about implicit references to `ActiveSheet` - these are the root cause behind roughly 40%<sup>1</sup> of all VBA questions asked on Stack Overflow, every day.

Unqualified `Range`, `Rows`, `Columns`, `Names`, and `Cells` calls, all implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet`... when you're in a standard module. When you're in a worksheet module's code-behind, they implicitly refer to *that sheet*. The simple fact that the same identical code does different things depending on where it's written, should be enough to be explicit about it.

Since this is all happening behind `Sheet1`, IMO the ideal qualifier would be `Me`. So instead of this:

> ```
> Sheet1.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
> ```

I would have that:

> ```
> Me.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
> ```

And then here:

> ```
> iLastRow = Range("R1:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row).Value
> ```

I'd have this:

> ```
> iLastRow = Me.Range("R1:R" & Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row).Value
> ```

Note that if you're in the code-behind for `Sheet1`, you *can* interchangeably use `Sheet1` and `Me`, ...but you shouldn't. Consistency is king. Seeing `Me` as a qualifier immediately reminds the reader that they're looking at code that's in a class module (a `Worksheet` is a class, `Sheet1` is a `Worksheet` instance; ditto for `Workbook` and `ThisWorkbook`). On the other hand, qualifying with a specific worksheet's codename makes that code usable from anywhere, i.e. if you want to move that code from `Sheet1.Worksheet_Change` to the `ThisWorkbook.SheetChange` handler, nothing would have to change and it would work identically.

---

#### Okay got it. Now what about performance?

Worksheet manipulations are inherently slow. Reading & writing cell values is slow, and resizing and formatting cells is even slower.

Surely you know of the "hold Ctrl down" trick? Hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, click on the row headings you want to hide, right-click once, pick "hide" once, and poof all the selected rows get hidden at once!

You can do exactly the same thing in VBA, using a little `Union` helper function - something like this:

```
Private Function CombineRanges(ByVal source As Range, ByVal toCombine As Range) As Range
    If source Is Nothing Then
        Set CombineRanges = toCombine
    Else
        Set CombineRanges = Union(source, toCombine)
    End If
End Function
```

Now all you'll be doing with `Range` objects, is dereferencing them - as opposed to accessing their members and mutating their state.

Before I share the resulting code, I'd like to add that there are probably certain things you want to *abstract* away into other members. I'd declare module-level `Const` values, to avoid *magic literals*, and I'd probably expose a `Property Get` members or two, to abstract as many concepts and expose them to other code if they need to - otherwise make them `Private`, doesn't hurt.

So anyway, here's my version:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const VisibilityToggleColumn As Long = 18 'column "R"
Private Const VisibilityToggleValue As String = "Show"

Public Property Get LastRow() As Long
    LastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, VisibilityToggleColumn).End(xlUp).Row
End Property

Public Property Get VisibilityToggleColumnValues() As Variant
    VisibilityToggleColumnValues = Me.Range(Me.Cells(1, VisibilityToggleColumn), Me.Cells(LastRow, VisibilityToggleColumn)).Value
End Property

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    ToggleApplicationState False

    Me.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

    Dim rowsToHide As Range
    Dim rowsToShow As Range

    Dim visibilityToggleValues As Variant
    visibilityToggleValues = VisibilityToggleColumnValues

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(visibilityToggleValues) To UBound(visibilityToggleValues)

        Dim currentCell As Range
        Set currentCell = Me.Cells(i, VisibilityToggleColumn)

        Dim currentToggle As Variant
        currentToggle = visibilityToggleValues(i, 1)

        If IsError(currentToggle) Then
            'if a cell contains an error, we don't want to hide it
            Set rowsToShow = CombineRanges(rowsToShow, currentCell)
        Else
            If StrComp(currentToggle, VisibilityToggleValue, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Set rowsToShow = CombineRanges(rowsToShow, currentCell)
            Else
                Set rowsToHide = CombineRanges(rowsToHide, currentCell)
            End If
        End If

    Next

    If Not rowsToShow Is Nothing Then rowsToShow.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If Not rowsToHide Is Nothing Then rowsToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True

CleanExit:
    ToggleApplicationState True
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Unhandled error in 'Worksheet_Change' handler: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume CleanExit
    Resume
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleApplicationState(ByVal enabled As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = enabled
    Application.EnableEvents = enabled
    Application.Calculation = IIf(enabled, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
End Sub

Private Function CombineRanges(ByVal source As Range, ByVal toCombine As Range) As Range
    If source Is Nothing Then
        Set CombineRanges = toCombine
    Else
        Set CombineRanges = Union(source, toCombine)
    End If
End Function
```

Notice I'm using the `StrComp` function to compare the strings with `vbTextCompare` - this ensures a case-insensitive comparison without the extra processing overhead of `LCase`/`LCase$` or `UCase`/`UCase$` conversions.

That code runs in just over 200ms<sup>2</sup>, with over 13,000 rows in column R - and there's probably still more room for improvements, but I'll leave it at that for now.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>By no scientific measurement whatsoever. It's just an extremely common mistake.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>Lazily measured with a very basic [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/timer-function) diff.</sub>

Comment: Matt, this is amazing.  The performance issue is completely fixed.  As always, your conceptual responses are so helpful; I think I owe a lot of my (albeit limited) coding knowledge to your responses between here and Stack Overflow.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Reading from the spreadsheet is slow. Best to work with a variant array. I didn't have any speed issues with either using. I don't see much else to speed it up. Used `LCase$` to guard against typos.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim start As Single
    start = Timer
    With Sheet1 'Explicitly qualifies everything that starts with '.' (Period)
        .Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim showHideCriteria As Variant
        showHideCriteria = .Range("R1:R" & lastRow).Value

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To UBound(showHideCriteria) ' Redundant  1 parameter
            If LCase$(showHideCriteria(i, 1)) = "show" Then ' Empty cells treated as vbNullString
            'If LCase$(Range("R" & i)) = "show" Then 'Uncomment this line and comment line above to compare speed.
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Debug.Print "Took " & Timer - start & " seconds"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It is still taking quite a while.  The timer you coded for says 2.5-3.5 seconds per cell modification.  Is that what you were getting?

Comment: I loaded up a blank spreadsheet. I was getting fractions of a second when I tested it. I've a feeling that how you have your sheet set up will matter more than any performance gains you could get from maximizing this code. Post your code, assuming it doesn't contain sensitive info, and get reviews for the rest of your code. ***Note***: Critiques to code aren't against the coder, they are to make the code better & more robust. Welcome to CodeReview!

Comment: For sure, I'm really new to coding, so I really appreciate the constructive criticism.  Is it possible here to upload a file? That is actually all of the code for this sheet right now.  I was given the book to add code for that one process, but the rest of the sheet has some pretty complicated formula work, which I unfortunately don't know enough about to critique or edit.  Could that be what is slowing it down?

Comment: Calculation mode being set to automatic could indeed make your code slower. I have an answer brewing FWIW.